# How to update a dictionary counter?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, counter

Lets say you have a dictionary counter as such:

themes_and_likes = {"fantasy":0, "horror":0}

How do you update it so that it increases whenever the respective words appear from the source file?

My answer was:

```
for i in usa_video_comments:

    if themes_and_likes["fantasy"]:
        themes_and_likes["fantasy"] += 1
    else:
        themes_and_likes["horror"] = 1
print(themes_and_likes)
```

where usa_video_comments was the source, the answer I recieved was

{'fantasy': 0, 'horror': 1}

which is wrong because the counter isn't continuously updated

Comment: Can you show how the file looks

Comment: The file is pretty big, but here a snippet of some of it:
[
        [ # Row  0
            'XpVt6Z1Gjjo',  #Video Id - Index 0
            "I've been following you from the start of your vine channel and have seen all 365 vlogs", #Comment Text - Index 1
            '3', #Likes - Index 2
            '0'], #Replies - Index 3
        [ # Row  1
            'XpVt6Z1Gjjo', #Video Id - Index 0
            'Say hi to Kong and maverick for me', #Comment Text - Index 1
            '3', #Likes - Index 2
            '0'#Replies - Index 3
        ]
    ]

Comment: Add it to the question and format it properly please

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement always evaluates to `False` because, 
`if themes_and_likes["fantasy"]:`  is becoming `if 0:` and in you aren't doing much in `else` statement either except assigning a value of 1 to it. Without knowing the structure of the file it is difficult to answer exactly. But assuming you know what you're doing here's a snippet that might help you.

```
themes_and_likes = {"fantasy":0, "horror":0}

for i in usa_video_comments: # assuming i is single line comment

    if 'fantasy' in i:
        themes_and_likes["fantasy"] += 1
    elif 'horror' in i:
        themes_and_likes["horror"] += 1

print(themes_and_likes)
```